# Не загружается файл с конфигурациями

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

У меня есть проект с название `ask`. В нем я задал переменную `PROJECT_ROOT` и изменил путь поиска шаблонов:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Проблема в том, что `Django` не видит этих изменений. Например, если я зайду в командную строку `Django` - окружения командой `./manage.py shell`, то увижу следующее:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from ask.settings import *
>>> print PROJECT_ROOT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'PROJECT_ROOT' is not defined
>>> print TEMPLATES
[{'DIRS': ['templates'], 'APP_DIRS': True, 'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug', 'django.template.context_processors.request', 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}, 'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates'}]
```

Куда делась моя переменная `PROJECT_ROOT` и почему в поле `DIRS` словаря `TEMPLATES` нет указанного мной пути ?

Comment: Похоже, что консоль действительно работает со старой версией кода. Помогает ли перезапуск консоли? Запускается ли при этом тестовый сервер? Если запускается, то можно разместить `print(PROJECT_ROOT)` прямо в `settings.py` и посмотреть результат при запуске тестового сервера командой `manage.py runserver`: он будет выведен в STDOUT

Comment: сделайте `import ask` и посмотрите что `ask.__file__` соответствует ожидаемому.